What does "to focus on things to complain about" mean?
In this video, the trainer advices that we should "focus on things to complain about". I don't quite get the meaning of the phrase "focus on things to complain about".
Using ChatGPT, it says that the phrase makes sense though not being used very common. The way the software explains the sentence is as follow:

To focus on things (that are being complained about).

But is it correct to parse the sentence it in this way?

I’m voting to close this question because the poster (me) didn't read the full sentence.

I believe you can delete your own question.

He doesn't say that we should focus on things to complain about (concentrate on bad things in our life that we might want to complain about).
Quite the opposite; he says that it's better to focus on things to be grateful for. We will be happier if we have a positive attitude to life.
